# How to access TestContext in Specflow 3.0 [BeforeTestRun] static Hook

Tags: testing, mstest, bdd, specflow, testcontext

I have started using Specflow 3.0 for .NET core tests project with built-in MSTest runner.

I encountered problem while trying to setup one-time method execution in order to persist bearer token value for all running tests in Specflow.

So my idea was to create [BeforeTestRun] Hook static method which would make HTTP request with given credentials. The problem is that those credentials are stored in .runsettings file, so I need to have MSTest's TestContext object in order to access dictionary property.

In Scenario's I'm injecting TestContext and it works fine, however I do not know how to access this object in static [BeforeTestRun] method. Is there any chance to create this object myself and store in static property?

[image: TestContext class]

As you see this is abstract class, so I guess Test Framework is automatically injecting concrete implementation in Scanarios with DI. How could I get this concrete implementation?

If solution is not present, would you suggest another approach how could I store configurable settings besides .runsettings so I could access them in static [BeforeTestRun] method without DI?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK I know the behaviour of TestContext in MSTest, you get in plain MSTest for every test your own instance of TestContext.
So you can't get an instance for the whole testrun.

What you could do is, that you do the HTTP request in the BeforeScenario hook of the first scenario that gets executed. There you can get to the TestContext instance without problems.

Comment: Thank you did exactly like that :) Seems to work fine.